# Change innerHTML in all <td> rows

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

How to change innerHTML in all rows?

This script only changes innerHTML in first row.

```html
<table>
<tr><td id="X">0</td></tr>
<tr><td id="X">0</td></tr>
</table>

<script>
if (document.getElementById("X").innerHTML == 0)
{ 
document.getElementById('X').innerHTML = '1';
} 
</script>
```

Comment: First of all you cannot have same `id`s for all the rows. `id` should be unique in entire document. Use a class instead.

Comment: id should be unique. Use class for this purpose.

Comment: Changed everything to class and used ''getElementsByClassName'' doesnt work.

Comment: @PlayerPhB What do you mean it doens't work? What does it do? Any errors in console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all you should not give same 'id' attribute multiple time in DOM. Bad practice. you can assign same 'class' instead.**

But even if this is the set elements with you then using following code will solve your problem

```
var tdList = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for(var i=0; i< tdList.length; i++){ 
  if(tdList[i].innerHTML.trim()=='0' && tdList[i].getAttribute('id') == "X")
  tdList[i].innerHTML = '1' 
}
```

Comment: there will be a tick sign with my answer click it if you found my solution most suitable

Answer (score 2):

You should use `class` attribute, not `id`. You should have unique ids of your elements on page.

So it should be like:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="X">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="X">0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script>
var els = document.getElementsByClassName("X");

for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
  els[i].innerHTML = '1';
}
</script>
```

[Here is JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Teo_van_kot/oceen5f7/)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldnt use id. id should be unique. Use class instead.

```html
<table>
<tr><td class="X">0</td></tr>
<tr><td class="X">0</td></tr>
</table>


<script>
var tds = document.getElementsByClassName("X");
for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++)
{
   tds[i].innerHTML = "1";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Works but instead of 1 i need to insert a image.
How to?

Comment: @PlayerPhB What stopping you to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this script and check,

```
<script>
var tableRow = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for(var i=0; i< tableRow.length; i++){
//Your logic here
tableRow[i].innerHTML = 1;
}
</script>
```

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u4g2L8b6/

Answer (score 0):

Don't use id for multiple selector .Try with [`querySelectorAll()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj7z_v4x-DUAhXLRY8KHVlxAwYQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FAPI%2FDocument%2FquerySelectorAll&usg=AFQjCNGw4XxpSz-PKB1SUB1yNenuYzkpUw) and `forEach` for iterate the element one bye one .For more specific  you could use classname

```js
document.querySelectorAll('tr td').forEach(function(a){
a.innerHTML = a.innerHTML.trim() == '0'?'1': a.innerHTML;
})
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td id="X" >0</td></tr>
<tr><td id="X" >0</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Id should be unique, Use like this

```js
var tds = document.querySelectorAll("#X td");
for (var prop in tds) {
    if(tds[prop].innerHTML == "0"){
      tds[prop].innerHTML = "1"
    }
}
```

```html
Before
<table border="1" width="100px">
<tr><td>0</td></tr>
<tr><td>0</td></tr>
</table>
After
<table id="X" border="1" width="100px">
<tr><td>0</td></tr>
<tr><td>0</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr><td id="X">0</td></tr>
<tr><td id="X">0</td></tr>
</table>

<script>
get_item = document.querySelectorAll("#X");
for (var i in get_item) {
    if(get_item[i].innerHTML == "0"){
      get_item[i].innerHTML = "1"
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Well it works but these doesnt < or > or <= or => how to make these work?

Answer (score 0):

Solution to < > <= =>

```html
<table>
<tr><td id="X">9</td></tr>
<tr><td id="X">10</td></tr>
<tr><td id="X">11</td></tr>
</table>

<script>
var tdList = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for(var i=0; i< tdList.length; i++){ 
  if(parseInt(tdList[i].innerHTML.trim())<'10' && tdList[i].getAttribute('id') == "X")
  tdList[i].innerHTML = 'Answer is here' 
}
</script>
```